# Nested Mongoose's schema with unique ids

Tags: mongoose, nested, schema, unique

I have a schema with a unique `_id`:

```
var _mySchema = new _mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      default: _string.getRandom // My function that creates a random string the way I want it to.
    }
});
```

I'm reusing this schema within an array of embedded documents within this schema:

```
_mySchema.add({
    items: [_mySchema]
});
```

This is an unlimited tree/directory structure. `items` can have `items`, which can have `items`, etc.

The problem is that Mongo/Mongoose accepts a non unique `_id` within `items`. Is this even possible to fix? I though it should work automatically, because it's using the same schema.

Comment: Every top level item will need a unique id, but the embedded items can be references to top level items. They don't need to be unique, so it won't be enforced that way.

Comment: The embedded items cannot be only references because I want them to actually be of type of this schema. So it's not possible to enforce unique ids this way?

Comment: It's not possible to enforce it across multiple top level items, but you can enforce it within it's own array of items. The only way to enforce it across all would be to create a top level item for every nested one you create.

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of having nested schemas, if they don't really "work".

Comment: The schema is enforced by mongoose, not by mongo. The indexes and unique constraints are handled by mongo, not mongoose. They aren't one and the same, and they don't translate perfectly. You can do `_mySchema.index({"items._id":1}, {unique: true})` and `_mySchema.index({"items.items._id": 1}, {unique: true})` which might help, but it can't be done recursively, and can't be compared across different levels of depth in the data structure.

Comment: Thanks you very much.